# popping an element of a queue at initialisation of for loop ends up popping the same element all the time

Tags: java, collections, queue

I am trying to use pop method as below in Java. I expect to see the strings in the order `"c", "b", "a"`. However, it prints out only `"c"` infinitely. Why does that happen?

```
Stack<String> a = new Stack<>();
a.push("a");
a.push("b");
a.push("c");
for(String i = a.pop(); !a.isEmpty() ;){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten the "increment" part of the for loop. You've got the initialization part (called once, which is why `i` remains `c` for ever) and the condition part, but you're missing the last part which is executed each iteration of the loop.

However instead of writing `for(String i = a.pop; !a.isEmpty(); i = a.pop())` I'd advise to use the more fitting while loop

```
while(!a.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(a.pop());
```

Comment: Actually l have not forgotten. I thought pop would be fine for increment part as well but it is not logical at all..

Comment: What do you mean it's not logical? Compare with `for(int i = 0;i < 10;)` and it's easy to see why it fails.

Comment: @deeperwhite `pop` is fine for the increment part, but you don't have one.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
for(String i = a.pop(); !a.isEmpty() ;)
```

with:

```
for(String i = a.pop(); !a.isEmpty() ; i = a.pop())
```

As it is, you're not replacing the value in `i`, and there's still elements in the stack. So you're just getting an infinite loop, and displaying the last value that you popped out, namely "c".